# Certificate fingerprint in iOS

Tags: ios, wifi, security

When I connect to a particular Wi-Fi network, it asks me to accept a certificate. I can check the certificate details, such as signatures and so on, but not the fingerprint. I'm fairly certain the certificate is correct so I accepted it.

Where can I find, in iOS, the certificates in use (such as this one I just accepted) and how can I see their fingerprints?

Comment: You can find profiles / certificates under Settings > General > Profile and tap on the profile for more information. I'm not familiar with 'fingerprint'.

Comment: @rwzdoorn: I don't have an entry named *Profile* in Settings > General. Could it be under a different name? (The fingerprint is a hash of the complete certificate, useful to verify it is the correct one.)